# Automatically return to Safari after Youtube video plays on iPhone

Tags: iphone, mobile, youtube

I'm trying to get the following functionality:

1. Embed a youtube video into a webpage
2. Autoplay the video when the user arrives on the page from a mobile device
3. Play video
4. Return to webpage

The only way I can seem to get the video to autoplay on an iPhone is to redirect to youtube when the user lands on the page - this is not good for me as the youtube app will not direct the user back to the webpage on video completion. I've embedded the youtube video as flash so currently the user has to click to play the video (but at least the webpage is displayed afterwards).

I've tried using Youtubes JS API but to no avail - it always seems to just load the app without returning to the webpage.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: AFAIK what you want to do can't be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution: switch to HTML5 video :-)